# Calling async in a loop without await

Tags: kotlin

I have a collection of functions and each function is called using async. No await is used (and must not be):

```
fun runTests() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        for (testSetup in testSetupClasses) {
            val setup = testSetup()
            runningSetups.add(setup)

            for (test in setup.tests) {
                val testInfo = test.value

                async {
                    testInfo.getTestToRunAsync()?.invoke { testResult ->
                        testInfo.testResult = testResult
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that because a loop is used to launch each async, the variable testInfo is inside of the async and this could potentially get overwritten each time the loop is processed. What I would like to do is move the async to a function and call the function instead. Something like this:

```
fun runTests() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        for (testSetup in testSetupClasses) {
            val setup = testSetup()
            runningSetups.add(setup)

            for (test in setup.tests) {
                val testInfo = test.value
                runTestAsync(testInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun runTestAsync(testInfo: TestInfo) {
    async {
        testInfo.getTestToRunAsync()?.invoke { testResult ->
            testInfo.testResult = testResult
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, async in runTestAsync is unresolved. How can I fix this? The one solution I can think of is to add GlobalScope.launch in the function, but this looks kind of ugly and I'm not sure if it's a major performance issue if I have a lot of calls to the function:

```
 suspend fun runTestAsync(testInfo: TestInfo) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            async {
                testInfo.getTestToRunAsync()?.invoke { testResult ->
                    testInfo.testResult = testResult
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "could potentially get overwritten" i don't think so.

Comment: `GlobalScope.async` ...

Comment: Why not? The async code runs asynchronously. By the time the loop moves on to the next item and the previous async doesn't end until some later loop iteration, the testInfo variable will have changed. Or are you saying it would not change?

Comment: No, don't think so.

Comment: I would expect each call to `async` to capture a newly initialized local `val testInfo` from that iteration of the loop.